# PSTricks Drawing: Symmetric Figure

Tags: pstricks

Consider the following picture:

[image: figure]

I would like to draw this figure using PSTricks.

My problem is the ends; the "cross" in the middle is no problem at all.

Here is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-4,-4)(4,4)
 \psset{fillstyle = solid}
  \psframe[fillcolor = black](-4,-4)(4,4)
  \multido{\i = 0+90}{4}{\rput{\i}(0,0){%
    \pspolygon[
      linecolor = white,
      fillcolor = white
    ](0,0)(0,2.5)(0.5,2.5)(0.5,0.5)(2.5,0.5)(2.5,0)}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

**Update**

The following figure shows the "bulge" clostest to the egde (in Herbert's answer), which I would like to get rit of. I would like to "flatten" the end to make it look more the the original picture.

[image: bulge]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\makeatletter
\def\psElement{\pst@object{psElement}}
\def\psElement@i{{%
  \addbefore@par{xunit=0.65,fillcolor=\pslinecolor,fillstyle=solid}%
  \use@par
  \pscustom[]{%
    \psline(0.5,0)(0.5,1)%
    \pscurve(0.7,1.25)(1,1.15)(0.9,1.05)(1.1,0.9)(1.4,1.1)(1.2,1.6)(0.9,1.7)(0.2,1.5)(0,1.2)
    \psline(0,0)
    \closepath}}}
\def\psmySymbol{\pst@object{psmySymbol}}
\def\psmySymbol@i(#1){{%
  \pst@killglue
  \use@par
  \multido{\i=0+90}{4}{\rput{\i}(#1){%
        \psElement\psscalebox{-1 1}{\psElement}}}}}
\makeatletter
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(6,2)
\psframe*[linecolor=black](-2,-2)(6,2)
\psmySymbol[linecolor=white](0,0)
\psmySymbol[linecolor=red!30](4,0)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With a modified path:

```
 \pscurve(0.7,1.25)(1,1.15)(0.9,1.05)(1.1,0.9)(1.4,1.1)(1.2,1.4)(0.9,1.5)%
         (0.2,1.4)(0,1.2)
```

[image]

Comment: play with the `xunit=0.65`

Comment: then modify the coordinates of the curve.

Comment: `\pscurve(0.7,1.25)(1,1.15)(0.9,1.05)(1.1,0.9)(1.4,1.1)(1.2,1.4)(0.9,1.5)%
         (0.2,1.4)(0,1.2)` It is also possible to use an arc

Comment: sue, but I do not really understand your problem.

Comment: see my edited answer